# How to get the StructLayoutAttribute.Pack field applied to a struct in c#

Tags: c#, struct, reflection, attributes

Im bulding a generic type, limited to some kind of structs, and need to validate that have [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)] attribute applied.

I validate struct kind in base constructor:

```
public abstract class IotDeviceData<T> where T : struct
{
  protected T _data;

  protected IotDeviceData()
  {
    IotDeviceData<T>.IsAnAllowedStruct();
    _data = new T();
  }
}
```

I can check that LayoutKind.Sequential is applied.

```
private static void IsAnAllowedStruct()
{
  var t = typeof(T);
  if(!t.IsLayoutSequential)
  {
    throw (new ArgumentException($"Struct type {t} must have a sequential layout."));
  }
}
```

But, how to check that Pack is 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the [`StructLayoutAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.structlayoutattribute?view=net-7.0) and inspect its `Pack` directly:

```
if ((type.StructLayoutAttribute?.Pack ?? 0) != 1) {
    throw (new ArgumentException($"Struct type {type} must have a pack of 1"));
}
```